# Laravel is not defined Only with Guest User

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-component

I would setup a subscription system for video channel model. I use Vuejs and laravel 5.3

in my blade template, i put this

```
    <script>
   window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
    <script>
```

All works fine in Auth mode (when user is login) but in guest mode my vuejs component dont work and I get this in my console

```
ReferenceError: Laravel is not defined
```

Screenshots 
https://image.ibb.co/bPJCWG/laravel_Vuejs_Error_Guest.jpg
Subscribers count disappear, nothing work

this my codes:

**Controller:**

```
public function show(Request $request, Channel $channel)
{
    $response = [
        'count' => $channel->subscriptionCount(),
        'user_subscribed' => false,
        'can_subscribe' => false,
    ];

    if($request->user())
    {
        $response = array_merge($response, [
            'user_subscribed' => $request->user()->isSubscribedTo($channel),
            'can_subscribe' => !$request->user()->ownsChannel($channel),
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $response
    ], 200);
}
```

**SubscribeButton.vue Component:**

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            //...
        }
    },
    props: {
        //...
    },
    methods: {
        getSubscriptionStatus () {
            this.$http.get('/subscription/' + this.channelSlug).then((response) => {
                this.subscribers = response.body.data.count;
                this.userSubscribed = response.body.data.user_subscribed;
                this.canSubscribe = response.body.data.can_subscribe;
            })
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.getSubscriptionStatus();
    }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

that's because `csrf` only works for authenticated users. You need to change your javascript part to take into consideration anonymous users, something like:

> @if (Auth::check())
>
> // your window.laravel js here
>
> @endif

Comment: Thanks Ali, unfortunately it doesnt solve the problem. the video player is setup with vuejs and videojs. It works fine in guest mode. But only Subscribe component give me this error. I don't understand